# Firestack react-native exception 'Failed to get default FIRDatabase instance'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, react-native

I went trough the following tutorial:

https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/announcing-firestack-for-firebase/

and I did all the steps.

I also created a Google Firebase project and I added the configuration parameters from the Web Setup in the configuration object for Firestack.

When I try to run the app I get the following error:

Exception 'Failed to get default FIRDatabase instance. Must call FIRApp.configure() before using FIRDatabase.' was thrown before invoking on target FirestackDatabase with params ("/events", "child_added", 7)

I'm using firebase v3.3.0, react-native-firestack v2.2.1, and react v15.3.1

I can't figure out why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anywhere in that tutorial link you provided to add the configuration of the database in the app delegate. In Swift/Obj-C open the app delegate, import Firebase, and add FIRApp.configure() to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    FIRApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

EDIT: with firestack configuring the app is different. Instead of FIRapp.configure() you configure the app with the following code.

```
const firestack = new Firestack()
firestack.configure().then(() => console.log("Project configured and ready to boot"));
```

Comment: Should I add the Firebase SDK manually so that I can import Firebase? Or should I use something already present in the Firestack framework? And if I use the one in Firestack, how should I do that? Sorry if this sound dumb, but I have no previous experience with XCode or Objective-C.

Comment: Firestack should have linked all the requirements for firebase during the setup. Try to import Firebase in your app delegate and see if you can add the above line. If not I would suggest avoiding manually adding the Firebase SDK. Its a pain especially if you don't have much experience with xcode. Instead use cocoapods. Firebase has a great reference for setting up their SDK(s) for iOS. https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was because I was calling "set persistent" before configure:

```
const firestack = new Firestack();

firestack.configure().then(() => {
    firestack.database.setPersistence(true);
});
```